# Compile using CL.exe with different toolset

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, linker, cl

I need to compile a program automatically with different platform toolsets. The compilation is done using `cl.exe` and `link.exe` like so:

```
cl.exe file.c /GS- /PlatformToolset=vc140xp /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Gm- /Od /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D \"WIN32\" /D \"_WINDOWS\" /D \"_UNICODE\" /D \"UNICODE\" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa\"\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo\"\" /Fp\"\" /diagnostics:classic /link %link_additional% /ENTRY:wWinMain /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFEST:EMBED  /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE \"kernel32.lib\" \"user32.lib\" \"gdi32.lib\" \"winspool.lib\" \"comdlg32.lib\" \"advapi32.lib\" \"shell32.lib\" \"ole32.lib\" \"oleaut32.lib\" \"uuid.lib\" \"odbc32.lib\" \"odbccp32.lib\" /DEBUG:NONE /MACHINE:%arch% /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:\"level = 'asInvoker' uiAccess = 'false'\" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1\
```

I'm using the switch `/PlatformToolset=vc140xp` but, the cl.exe doesn't seem to reconginze it, i get an error:

`Unknown Option: /PlatformToolset`

Is there a way you can change toolset using cl.exe, without msbuild and vcproj ?

Comment: `cl.exe` is part of the toolset. Once you start one of the several `cl.exe`s you have already chosen a toolset, probably by having that one in the PATH.

Comment: @Bo Persson can you set a toolset from command line in vcvarsall ? Or is a vcvarsall a part of toolset?

Comment: I prefer to build from the IDE so I haven't been experimenting much with the command line builds, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase someone need it, i was able to solve this isuue. i added this option to cl.exe:

```
/D \"_USING_V110_SDK71_\"
```

And also i modified this option:

```
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
```

to

```
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01
```

After the application runs succesfully on windows xp. You might encounter some problems if you are heavily useing crt in your exe, in my exe i only needed CRT to define Tls callbacks, they do not work without CRT, so i guess maybe this is why this worked for me