# Change Platform Toolset when compiling from CMD

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmd, compilation

I would like to compile a `C++` program via Visual Studio command line tools. I would like to target the executable for `32 bit Windows XP`. Tried compiling it the usual way, using `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`, but it doesn't work on `Windows XP`, though runs fine on my `Windows 10` machine.

Steps I take:

- Open `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`.
- `cd` to the project directory. There I'll have 2 folders `sources` and `headers`, which shall contain `.cpp` and `.h` files respectively.
- Execute command `cl sources\*.cpp /EHsc /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x050103 /I headers /I <path to boost> /link /libpath <path to boost>\boost_1_77_0\bin\x86\lib\libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-s-x32-1_77.lib /out:exec_xp.exe` (the project uses the `boost` library).

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325589/compile-using-cl-exe-with-different-toolset), but it doesn't work. `/D \"_USING_V110_SDK71_\"` seems to do nothing, and the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01` piece isn't recognized by the compiler.

I have learnt from [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-160) that we should install deprecated Toolset to compile for `WinXP`. I went ahead to `Visual Studio Installer` and installed the `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]`, as said in the tutorial.

But what now? How can I use this Toolset? I can't find it anywhere on my computer, let alone use it! `Visual Studio Installer` says it's located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools`, but it's too vague.

**UPD:**

Tried with `msbuild /p:PlatformToolset=v141_xp`, getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(439,
5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141_xp (Platform Toolset = 'v141_xp') cannot be found. To build using the v141_
xp build tools, please install v141_xp build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools
by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution"
```

Which suggests, the compiler doesn't see the `v141_xp` toolset. I wonder why? It's installed for sure, I did it via the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Have you tried using `MSBuild` from the command line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019 ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I haven't, but I think I'm gonna try compiling from a windows XP virtual machine. Thank you for a tip, if I fail this time too, gonna turn to your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you could try to set the [PlatformToolset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview?view=msvc-160#platformtoolset-property):

`msbuild myProject.vcxproj /p:PlatformToolset=…`

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Now I kind of got lost, since I installed the `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]`, but unable to locate it. I've tried to retarget the solution to the Toolset, but it just doesn't show up as an option in the menu. Is it because I have VS 2019 and this Toolset is for VS 2017?

Comment: @winwin Whether you want to use `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]` in cmd? If so , you could try to use `msbuild myProject.vcxproj /p:PlatformToolset=v141_xp` 
"I've tried to retarget the solution to the Toolset, but it just doesn't show up as an option in the menu."What does it mean?

Comment: I've tried both doing the command you suggested from the command line AND from the IDE, but it shows that the compiler couldn't locate the build tools. I've updated the question.

Comment: @winwin I suggest you could try to remove the VCTargetsPath system variable.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.